# Windows 10 UWP UserControl with customizable content

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to make a user control in Windows 10 UWP with changing content.

I know how to make a simple user control, but I need a user control like this:

```
<Controls:UserControl x:Name="Usercontrol1" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Row="1">
    <Controls:UserControl.MainContent>
        <Grid x:Name="Content">
            //Items are here
        </Grid>
    </Controls:UserControl.MainContent>
</Controls:UserControl>
```

I have Grid in my user control that is empty and I want to give this grid different items in every page. I want a way to set a grid for my user control in the page, then add this grid to my user control instead of that empty grid.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do this, you need to create a `MainContent` dependency property in the code-behind of your user control and display it using a `ContentPresenter`.

Suppose your user control is defined in `MyControl.xaml` and `MyControl.xaml.cs`.

## Creating the `MainContent` dependency property

Inside the `UserControl` class definition in `UserControl.xaml.cs` add the following:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MainContentProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register( 
      "MainContent", 
      typeof( object ), 
      typeof( MyControl ), 
      new PropertyMetadata( default( object ) ) );

public object MainContent
{
    get { return ( object ) GetValue( MainContentProperty ); }
    set { SetValue( MainContentProperty, value ); }
}
```

As a shortcut in Visual Studio you can write `propdp` or `dependencyProperty` (depending on your version) and press the **Tab** key to automatically fill out a code snippet for the whole property.

## Adding `ContentPresenter`

Inside the `MyControl.xaml` find the place where you want to display the content and put a `ContentPresenter` there with a binding to the `MainContent` property.
There are several ways to do this.

**The newest technique with `x:Bind` syntax**

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{x:Bind MainContent}" />
```

**Using binding with element** - here you will need to add a `x:Name` attribute to the `UserControl` element itself, call it `RootControl` for example, and then create the binding like this:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MainContent, ElementName=RootControl}" />
```

**Using binding with `DataContext`** - in the constructor of the `UserControl` in `MyControl.xaml.cs` you can set the `DataContext` - `this.DataContext = this;` and then write simply:

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MainContent}" />
```

## Usage

Now your `UserControl` is ready and you can use it like this:

```
<local:MyControl>
  <local:MyControl.MainContent>
     <!-- some content :-) -->
     <Image Source="Assets/LockScreenLogo.png" Width="100"/>
  </local:MyControl.MainContent>
</local:MyControl>
```

Comment: It's worked but I have a problem. my items in the mycontnet of usercontrol can not clicked or selected. How can I solve it?

Comment: Very nice, I recommend using the second way to bind the MainContent (and any other attributes), so when used, the inner elements will keep their defined DataContext, otherwise the MyControl will become their DataContext

Comment: But how can I make an `ElementName` Binding work inside the UserControl `MainContent`? Example: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=OuterTextBlock}"/>`