# UWP/WinUI3 Binding by ElementName inside UserControl custom Content DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, uwp, winui-3

What I've done is [created a simple UserControl with MainContent DependencyProperty in UWP/WinUI3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39313502/windows-10-uwp-usercontrol-with-customizable-content)

Basically it looks like this:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="This is the Text that should show up inside the UserControl" x:Name="OuterTextBlock"/>

<Controls:MyUserControl>
    <Controls:MyUserControl.MainContent>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=OuterTextBlock}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Controls:MyUserControl.MainContent>
</Controls:MyUserControl>
```

The problem is, that the `ElementName` binding does not work. Specifying elements that are defined in the Usercontrol itself, works: `ElementName=InnerTextBlock`

```xml
<UserControl [...]>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="This is the Text inside the UserControl itself" x:Name="InnerTextBlock"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{x:Bind MainContent, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

So there must be some boundary to access the Parent ElementName outside the UserControl. I have no idea how to solve this. I've seen there is also a `CustomControl` and a `ContentControl`, but is this the right type to use? I am wondering why the exact same pattern for a `Button` works, but not for the `UserControl`!?

```xml
<TextBlock Text="This is the Text that should show up inside the UserControl" x:Name="OuterTextBlock"/>

<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=OuterTextBlock}"/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Note: I've not used `[ContentProperty(Name = "MainContent")]` on the MyUserControl just to avoid any other problems. But that'd be the next step to get rid of `<Controls:MyUserControl.MainContent>` as additional lines.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I am afraid that the `TextBlock` defined in the consuming view cannot bind to an element that is defined in `MyUserControl.xaml` using an `ElementName`.</strike>

`ElementName` only works when both elements reside in the same [XAML namescope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-namescopes?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

If you want to be able to expose the outer text from the `UserControl`, you could do this using a property:

```
public string OuterText => OuterTextBlock.Text;
```

**XAML:**

```
<Controls:MyUserControl x:Name="uc">
    <Controls:MyUserControl.MainContent>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding OuterText, ElementName=uc}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Controls:MyUserControl.MainContent>
</Controls:MyUserControl>
```

> I don't think this will work, as the MyUserControl does not know the OuterTextBlock.Text, as it is outside

Sorry, I thought `OuterTextBlock` was included in the `UserControl`.

If not, `x:Bind` should work:

```
<TextBlock Text="This is the Text that should show up inside the UserControl" x:Name="OuterTextBlock"/>

<Controls:MyUserControl x:Name="uc" Tag="test">
    <Controls:MyUserControl.MainContent>
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind OuterTextBlock.Text, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Controls:MyUserControl.MainContent>
</Controls:MyUserControl>
```

Comment: Where should the code behind be placed? I don't think this will work, as the `MyUserControl` does not know the `OuterTextBlock.Text`, as it is outside. And why does the button has the same namescope, but the usercontrol not?

Comment: Sorry, I thought `OuterTextBlock` was included in the `UserControl`. See my edit. You should be able to use `x:Bind` then.

Comment: That makes sense now. But what if I have a contentcontrol inside this `MainContent` where I cannot bind the datatemplates via `x:Bind`? Then I'd need `Binding` + `ElementName`. And that does not work here it seems. It might sound like a special edge case, but that is what I really want to do. Isn't there a way to get Binding to work?

Comment: You cannot bind to an element in another namescope.

Comment: And why does it work for the `Button` content?